# React with .NET multiple build commands for each environment

Tags: reactjs, .net, npm, environment-variables

I have a solution consisting of a React app front-end with .NET6 Web API backend.  Both projects are managed and published from the same solution.  The React app was created with Visual Studio 2022 using the Standalone React App template with the option selected for integration with a .NET API.  This is a somewhat new template and architecture offered in VS.  Essentially there's a proxy config that allows the React app and the API to both be published and hosted together in a single app service.

Currently I can publish this solution to an Azure App Service successfully.  Both the React app and API are published correctly.  To do this I right-click =>> publish on the API project, not the React app.  This works because the React app is referenced in the API .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\content-manager\content-manager.esproj">
          <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The React app's build is then triggered by this setting in its .esproj file:

```
<!-- Command to create an optimized build of the project that's ready for publishing -->
<ProductionBuildCommand>npm run build</ProductionBuildCommand>
```

This all works fine for production deployments.

Goal - I want to setup multiple .env files in the React project for dev, test and production, then use them respectively with multiple run commands during publishing.

If I publish using my test publish profile in VS2022, I want the React app to run the test build that references .env.test.

How can I do this if Visual Studio only provides the one  setting?